# add active class to link with sf2 and twig

Tags: php, url, symfony, twig

following simple code:

```
<li><a href="{{ path('_list') }}">List</a></li>
```

is there a simple way to add an `class="active"` if the current page matches the `_list` route?

using the newest PR-Release of symfony2 and twig as template engine

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Twig allows for conditionals and the Request object is available throughout the application. If you are including the template, to get the route you want to use:

```
app.request.attributes.get('_route')
```

If you are using the render function, you want to use:

```
app.request.attributes.get('_internal')
```

With that, you should be able to use:

```
class="{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') == '_list' %}active{% endif %}"
```

or shorter:

```
class="{{ app.request.get('_route') == '_list' ? 'active' }}"
```

Comment: yeah, i found the `_route` param a few minutes ago in the sourcecode, but i passed it as a variable to the template, because i didn't know that i can access the request variable directly from twig. thats awesome, thanks !

Comment: Might be more recent, but app.request.get('_route') also works.

Comment: Shorter version: class="{{ app.request.attributes.get('_route') == '_list' ? 'active' }}"

Comment: Based on previous comments shortest version so far is `{{ app.request.get('_route') == '_list' ? 'active' }}`

Answer (score 24):

Sometimes you don't want to do exact matching of a route.  For those cases, you can use the "starts with" conditional logic of twig.

As an example, lets assume you are working with books.  You have the following routes: book, book_show, book_new, book_edit.  You want the navigation item Book to be highlighted for any of those cases.  This code would accomplish that.

```
<a class="{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') starts with 'book' %}active{% endif %}">Books</a>
<a class="{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') starts with 'author' %}active{% endif %}">Authors</a>
```

This example works with at least Symfony 2.3.x

Answer (score 23):

**Shortest version:**

```
{% set route = app.request.get('_route') %}

 <li class="{{ route starts with 'post' ? 'open' }}"></li>
 <li class="{{ route starts with 'category' ? 'open' }}"></li>
```

Sometimes useful:

```
{% set route = app.request.get('_route') %}

<li class="{{ 'post' in route ? 'open' }}"></li>
<li class="{{ 'category' in route ? 'open' }}"></li>
```

Answer (score 10):

With ternary operator:

```
    {% set route = app.request.attributes.get('_route') %}
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li {{ route ==  'profile_index' ? 'class="active"' }}><a href="{{ path('profile_index') }}"><i class="icon-profile position-left"></i> My Profile</a></li>
        <li {{ route ==  'influencers_index' ? 'class="active"'}}><a href="{{ path('influencers_index') }}"><i class="icon-crown position-left"></i> Influencers</a></li>
        <li {{ route ==  'task_manager_index' ? 'class="active"'}}><a href="{{ path('task_manager_index') }}"><i class="icon-alarm-check position-left"></i> Task Manager</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 6):

This is done with symfony 3.4, but probably something similar can be done with SF2.

src\AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Twig;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    private $requestStack;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('activeMenu', [$this, 'activeMenu'])
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Pass route names. If one of route names matches current route, this function returns
     * 'active'
     * @param array $routesToCheck
     * @return string
     */
    public function activeMenu(array $routesToCheck)
    {
        $currentRoute = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->get('_route');

        foreach ($routesToCheck as $routeToCheck) {
            if ($routeToCheck == $currentRoute) {
                return 'active';
            }
        }

        return '';
    }
}
```

Add this to services.yml

```
services:
    #... some other services
    AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension:
        arguments: ["@request_stack"]
```

Usage:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="{{ activeMenu(['form', 'edit_form']) }}"><a href="{{ path('form') }}">Form</a></li>
    <li class="{{ activeMenu(['list']) }}"><a href="{{ path('list') }}">List</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: briliant solution, i'm using now, thank u +1

Answer (score 3):

i found a very good Bundle that handles all this stuff automagically:

https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers.  If the url changes or dies, then this post is rendered useless.  If you just want to post a link, write it as a comment under the question.

Answer (score 1):

SF2.2

```
{{ dump(app.request.server.get('PATH_INFO')) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Symfony2.3, in Twig, try this to get uri:

```
{{ dump(app.request.server.get("REQUEST_URI")) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found more efficient to know if we are on the active page and the link or not:

in file xx.html.twig :
In on your header file

```
{% set route_name = app.request.attributes.get('_route') %}
```

And add in html class of twig

```
{% if route_name matches '{^issue}' %}active{% endif %}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I do it (using Symfony 2.6)

```
<li {% if app.request.get('_route') == '_homepage' %} class="active" {% endif %}><a href="{{ path('_homepage') }}">Student</a></li>
```

`'_homepage'` is the name of route in `routing.yml` of your bundle and the route looks like this

```
_homepage:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: CoreBundle:Default:index }
```

Answer (score -4):

class="class_name {% if loop.index0 == 0 %}CLASSNAME{% endif %}"

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.